# How to optimize/rethink a Rank over Partition query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fairly straight forward query that takes forever to run - roughly a second per row that's returned.  The issue is the rank over partition approach, but I'm not sure how to rewrite it (cross apply?)

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Query:

```
Select orders.orderid
    ,prescriptions.patientid as Rx_PtID
    ,prescriptions.prescriptiontypeid
    ,prescriptions.prescriptionid
    ,letter_history.employeename
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY prescriptions.prescriptionid ORDER BY letter_history.letter_date ASC) AS orank --Assigns ID based on first printing
from letter_history,orders,prescriptions
where letter_history.description LIKE CONCAT('%', orders.orderid, '%')
    AND prescriptions.patientid = orders.patientid
    AND orders.ordertypeid = 999                    --Exam Orders Only
    AND CONVERT(varchar(10),orders.orderdate, 120) = CONVERT(varchar(10),prescriptions.rxdate, 120)
    AND CAST(orders.ordereddate as date) >= @DateFrom
    AND CAST(orders.ordereddate as date) <= @DateTo
```

Comment: You can't optimise a leading wildcard: `LIKE CONCAT('%', orders.orderid, '%')`. You can, however, stop converting date and time columns to a `varchar` to cmpare them. Why is `orderdate` being treated as both a `varchar` **and** a `date` in the `WHERE`? What data type actually is it?

Comment: Also, it's far beyond time to join to rest of us in 1992 onwards. The ANSI-89 `JOIN` syntax was replaced 27 years ago. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: While both dates are `DATETIME`, not all of them have times (it's inconsistent), so we need to drop the times off to get accurate counts.

Comment: So why the `varchar`?

Comment: Changing `varchar` to `date` has no appreciable effect on the time to complete the query in this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason the `rank()` seems slow is that *all* the data needs to be processed in order for it to return results.

If you run the query without the `rank()` it will look fast -- because it is faster to return the first few results than the whole result set.  You could check this out by make this a subquery and using `count(*)` to see the performance.

Also:  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.